# Como manipular o tamanho (width/height) da janela do navegador com JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

existe alguma maneira de "setar" o tamanho da janela? Não estou me referindo ao resize e sim mudar os valores da janela, ou seja, redimensionar com valores específicos...
É preciso que seja na mesma janela onde será aplicado os js e não em uma nova janela com o open() por exemplo.

Comment: Queres setar o tamanho da janela do browser? ou seja a janela que o OS tem para o Browser?

Comment: Eu achei [isso](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5238603/1267304) e [isso](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resizeTo), mas não acho que seja possível com javascript puro.